# How to add/get data in dynamic view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have parent Linear layout of id "layout" (it is inside a scroll view),
Inside this parent layout(linear layout) ,i generate custom constraint layout, that has many views (Textviews,image,button,editText..etc).

Here is the Layout of the Parent view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear">

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/scroll">


            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                <!--inside it will be many constraint view childs-->
                />
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_rounded_btn"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/finish_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Finish" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom constraint layout(child):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/child">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_field"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="138dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/uploud_field_pic_btn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uploud_field_pic_btn"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:background="#1aB00020"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/uploud_icon"
        android:text="@string/insert_picture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_size_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/size"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/custom_name_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/custom_name_reg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView_size_in_reg_custom"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="field size"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/custom_name_in_reg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_price_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView_price_in_custom_reg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_size_custom_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_size_custom_reg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView_price_in_custom_reg"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="price/hr"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_size_in_reg_custom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_size_in_reg_custom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_available_day_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/availability_days"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_price_custom_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_price_custom_reg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView_available_day_in_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:hint="ex: (sun-wed)-mon"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_price_in_custom_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_price_in_custom_reg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_available_time_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/availability_time"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_available_day_custom_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_available_day_custom_reg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView_available_time_in_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:hint="ex:(8am-11pm)-(2pm-5pm)"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_available_day_in_custom_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_available_day_in_custom_reg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_to_be_filled_custom_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_name_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/custom_name_in_reg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_field" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/custom_name_in_reg"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="field name /number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uploud_field_pic_btn" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I generate this custom constraint view dynamically ,many times linearly inside its linear view parent in my activity Class as follow:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {

        // Add the text layout to the parent layout
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_owner_register_layout, parentLayout, false);

        // In order to get the view we have to use the new view with text_layout in it
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.child);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_to_be_filled_custom_reg);
        textView.setText("Field # " + (i + 1));

        // Add the text view to the parent layout
        parentLayout.addView(constraintLayout);
    }
```

now i want to set and get the data from each constraint child view that has (Edit texts and an Image) , i know how to access the child of the parent but i have no idea how to access the views(edit texts and image) of each one of the children group .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the simple way is you save ConstraintLayout in list, so you can easier set and get the data.

Comment: could u explain more?

Comment: You create an instance of ConstraintLayout list `List<ConstraintLayout> constraints = new ArrayList<>();`. And each loop you `parentLayout.addView(constraintLayout);`, you also `constraints.add(constraintLayout);`. So in case you want set or get data in specific position, you can use `constraints.get(position).findViewById(R.id.textView_to_be_filled_custom_reg)`

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanHashemEl-feraly Disadvantage of using this approach is that you have to use **findViewById** each time. Also if you remove/add any view run time then you have to keep your list i.e `List<ConstraintLayout>` in sync with **parentLayout**

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view holder class `ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`  then set it as a tag for each inflated view `view.setTag(viewHolder);`

```
ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(constraintLayout);
constraintLayout.setTag(viewHolder);
parentLayout.addView(constraintLayout);
```

While retrieving back use the following

```
View childView = parentLayout.getChildAt(position);
ItemViewHolder vHolder = (ItemViewHolder) childView.getTag();
```

Here is how custom view holder will look like

```
protected class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't there any simpler way other than creating a class ?

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanHashemEl-feraly This is the cleaner approach, same like how we create `RecyclerViewAdapter`. We create **a) Adapter class b) ViewHolder c) then create view d) bindview**. for creating new class concern you just need to **create an inner class**

Comment: what is ButterKnife? also what does getTag() do ?